# Searchkick reindex failure

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, searchkick

I try to run `rake searchkick:reindex CLASS=Doctor`but I got this error:

```
rake aborted!
Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::BadRequest: [400] {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"analyzer [searchkick_word_index] not found for field [word]"}],"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Failed to parse mapping [_default_]: analyzer [searchkick_word_index] not found for field [word]","caused_by":{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"analyzer [searchkick_word_index] not found for field [word]"}},"status":400}
/usr/local/bundle/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.15/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/base.rb:146:in `__raise_transport_error'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.15/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/base.rb:256:in `perform_request'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.15/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/http/faraday.rb:20:in `perform_request'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.15/lib/elasticsearch/transport/client.rb:125:in `perform_request'
```

My elasticsearch version is 2.2.0 and I am using ruby 2.2.0.
My other branch works fine and I could not find why this happen in my old branch.

Here is the model:
[Doctor.rb](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1dc4e2c98e3b9e2419ec)

What are the possibilities that causing this?

Thanks!

Comment: can you give me the output of curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/your_index/_mapping'

Comment: @Dias 
# curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/name'
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"index_not_found_exception","reason":"no such index","resource.type":"index_or_alias","resource.id":"name","index":"name"}],"type":"index_not_found_exception","reason":"no such index","resource.type":"index_or_alias","resource.id":"name","index":"name"},"status":404}#

Comment: in the curl request give your index name 

curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/your_index_name/_mapping

To get all index names as a list

curl 'localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v'

Comment: @Dias I got empty index when trying curl 'localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v'. Do you know why?

Comment: That means you have not created any index.
update your question with your Model source code in which you are trying to index

Comment: @Dias I updated my question.